# Jupyter notebook: disable autocommit when using the %sql magic keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm using the `%sql` and `%%sql` magic keywords in Jupyter notebook to delete sql records.

I connect to the db using the following:

```
%load_ext sql
%sql oracle+cx_oracle://user/pwd@tnsname
```

However when I execute a delete statement, it seems a commit is automatically done afterwards:

```
%%sql
delete from my_table
```

After this DML operation, when I open another session and perform a `select count(*) from my_table` the result is zero.

How can I disable auto-commit with the use of `%sql` magic keyword?

Addendum, when I use the `%config SqlMagic.autocommit=False` option, I have:

> UserWarning: Config option `autocommit` not recognized by `SqlMagic`.  Did you mean `autolimit`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the config before to run the connection:

```
%config SqlMagic.autocommit=False
```

For Databases is always by default true, in fact it is always true. If you need to connect for example to IMPALA, you need to disable it first.

```
%config SqlMagic.autocommit=False
%sql impala://hserverhost:port/default?kerberos_service_name=hive&auth_mechanism=GSSAPI
```

Comment: when I use the `%config` option I get __UserWarning: Config option `autocommit` not recognized by `SqlMagic`.  Did you mean `autolimit`__

Comment: No, I meant autocommit. I am using the ipython-sql library , which is loaded using the %load_ext iPython extension. Are you using the same ??

Comment: I guess I'm using the same, e.g. `%load_ext sql`. I printed the output error message, which states "Did you mean autolimit?" - see edit in my question.